# How do I use an if statement in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am want to use an if statement to only console.log is there is a "todo.title". But when I write out the if statement a red line appears below the if statement.

Ok, let me explain this problem with a bit more detail. This is what the webpage looks like: [image]

All the initial todo items are coming from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos. And I added a new line called "test" via the input box. When I clicked on the check box for "delectus aut autem", it showed the proper console.log. But I when I clicked on the checkbox for "Test", it showed that error message in the console.

I am trying to change the code so that it will only console for the items that came from the jsonplaceholder website and I am trying to do that by saying "only if there is a todo.title, then console.log, but if not do not console.log anything. Here is my new code:

```
onToggle(todo) {
  // Toggle in UI
  todo.completed = !todo.completed;
  // Toggle on server
  this.todoService.toggleCompleted(todo).subscribe(    
    todo => { 
      if (todo.title) {
        console.log(todo);
      }        
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a linting issue because your code is not formatted.

Comment: Right-click in the text editor and select Format Document. Does the issue disappear?

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the code with the red underline, text will appear to tell you what the problem is. In this case, you need to wrap your `if` statement in a function.

Comment: I edited the question to make more sense for what I am talking about

Comment: 1. Web service is throwing some exception, so go to Network Tab and see the request and the exception details in the response. 2 Keep a breakpoint in the server function and see if it is getting hit and debug

Answer (score 4):

It should be `.subscribe( () => { <your code (if...)> } );`

Comment: I edited the question to make more sense for what I am talking about

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be needing something on the lines of the following, as your if statement would always be true if you compare the same two objects.

```
onToggle(todo){
    //Toggle in UI
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    //Toggle on server
    this.todoService.toggleCompleted(todo).subscribe( ()=>
       if(todo.title){
           console.log(todo.title);
       }
    );  
}
```

Comment: Note that todoType would be replaced with the type that you expect the returnedTodo to be and returnedTodo is the object that is returned from the todoService.

Comment: I edited the question to make more sense for what I am talking about

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, no problem, see if the above helps you out any. (note this was just typed into the text box, so there could be minor syntax issues, but it looks like it should be good).